# Alpine.js multiple dynamic select with additional description

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, fetch-api, alpine.js

This is what I have with Alpine.js at the moment (Blade syntax):

```
<div x-data='{
    selectedGroup: "{{ old('problem_group') }}",
    selectedType: "{{ old('problem_type') }}",
    problemType: "",
    isLoading: false,
    typeDisabled: false,
    showAlert: false,
    groups: {!! json_encode($problems) !!},
    groupDescription: "",
    types: [],
    fetchProblemTypes() {
        fetchProblemTypes(this.selectedGroup, this.groups, this.groupDescription, this.isLoading, this.types)
    },
    changeGroupDescription() {
        this.groupDescription = this.groupDescription
    }
}'>
    <select name="problem_group[]"
        id="problem_group"
        x-model="selectedGroup"
        @change="fetchProblemTypes"
        x-bind:disabled="isLoading"
        class="form-control">

        <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
        <template x-for="group in groups" :key="group.id">
            <option x-text="group.name" :value="group.id"></option>
        </template>
    </select>

    <div x-show="groupDescription !== ''">
        <div x-text="groupDescription"></div>
    </div>

    <select name="problem_type[]"
        id="problem_type"
        x-model="selectedGroup"
        @change="fetchProblemTypes"
        x-bind:disabled="isLoading"
        class="form-control">
        
        <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
        <template x-for="group in groups" :key="group.id">
            <option x-text="group.name" :value="group.id"></option>
        </template>
    </select>

    <!-- Description of problem type here -->

    <button type="button" class="line__new">Add a line</button>
</div>
```

The initial idea is as follows: present a user with 2 selects, when the `#problem_group` has been selected, display a description in the separate DIV of that current option (initially stored in `groups` variable) and fetch a POST request to the server that will give the list of problem_types of that current problem_group.

After selecting the problem_type, display the description in the separate DIV also.
On `.line__new` click, make a new line with same selects with the same functionality.
Since this form will be sent without AJAX, but with a regular POST request, validation may fail and user will be redirected back to the page with old data already pre-filled in those selects.

This is what I have came up with so far:

```
function fetchProblemTypes(selectedGroup, groups, groupDescription, isLoading, types) {
    let groupsOA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(groups))
    let description = groupsOA.find(o => o.id == selectedGroup);

    isLoading = true;

    fetch(router.fetchProblemTypes, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-Token': token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            group: selectedGroup,
        }),
    })
        .then(r => {
            if (!r.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok')
            }

            return r.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            types.splice(0, types.length, ...data);
            groupDescription = description.description;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            Swal.fire({
                title: ':(',
                text: error.responseText,
                icon: 'error',
            });
        })
        .finally(() => {
            isLoading = false;
        })
}
```

Server returns a response of an array of objects, like this:

```
[
    {"id":1, "name":"Type 1", "description":"Some type description"}, 
    {"id":2, "name":"Type 2", "description":"Some other type description"}, 
    {"id":3, "name":"Type 3", "description":"Some 3rd type description"},
    ...
]
```

So, two questions:

1. **Although I change the description in my `fetchProblemTypes()` function, it won't appear on the box**, but console.log(description.description) will return the actual string. I have a very similar select with similar functionality and I rewrote the logic from there.
2. With multiple lines, each containing 2 selects and 2 descriptions, what may be the better course of action, if any, to prefill/preselect/prefetch everything on page load, if there is an old data in request (provided by Laravel with `{{ old('field_name') }}`)?

Comment: The basic problem here is that the varibles passed to *fetchProblemTypes()* are passed by value (JS works in this way), so are only updated locally into this function...
[here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/) some hints about that

Comment: Also: the  two *<select>* can't have the same *x-model* and  the same variable *groups* containing the options (and the same *id*). When you add rows, all these elements will be replicated again and again...